# Toggle Many Animations and CSS Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have the below code that I am trying to toggle between.  I thought I might be able to add/remove classes and it would work but it doesn't seem to.  I tried toggle but that didn't work either.  Is there a simple way that on the second click everything reverts back?

```
$( ".next" ).click(function() {
$('.triangle').animate({  borderSpacing: -180 }, {
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');

$('.engine').css('background-image','url(/Incubator/wp-content/themes/incubator/images/basketball.jpg)');
$('.info-block').animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 1000);
$('.triangle').animate({"margin-left": "380px"}, 1000);
$('.alt').css('display', 'block');
$('.main').css('display', 'none');
$('.messy').fadeOut("slow");
$('.compete').fadeIn("slow");
$(this).removeClass("next");
$(this).addClass("back");
});


$( ".back" ).click(function() {
$('.triangle').animate({  borderSpacing: 0 }, {
    step: function(now) {
      $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
      $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
      $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');

$('.engine').css('background-image','url(/Incubator/wp-content/themes/incubator/images/engine.jpg)');
$('.info-block').animate({"margin-left": "800px"}, 1000);
$('.triangle').animate({"margin-left": "722px"}, 1000);
$('.alt').css('display', 'none');
$('.main').css('display', 'block');
$('.messy').fadeIn("slow");
$('.compete').fadeOut("slow");
$(this).removeClass("back");
$(this).addClass("next");
});
```

and the HTML

```
<div data-speed="5" class="engine parallax">
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div data-pos="550" class="next fade-in triangle"></div>
        <div data-pos="550" class="fade-in">
            <h3 class="messy">Get messy in the Incubator!</h3>
            <h3 class="compete">Compete in the Incubator!</h3>
        </div>
            <div data-pos="550" class="fade-in info-block">
                <p class="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p class="alt">Test text here sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <a href="">Get started today</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try substituting single `click` event , handler to toggle effects at `.triangle` element for adding removing `.next` `.back` `class` to toggle effects.

Added `easing:` at `,'linear'` , where options property `easing` not appear set ?; added `complete` callback at `.animate()` included block beginning with `$(".engine").css` within `complete` callback .

```js
// set `.triangle` `.data("clicked")` `false`
var t = $(".triangle").data("clicked", false)
// save `css` `matrix()` positions
, props = []
// reset `matrix`
, p = props.length > 0 ? props.reverse() : false;
// define both initial, reset animations at single `click` event
t.click(function() {
  // cache value of `.data("clicked")` , initial: `false`
  var d = $(this).data("clicked") === true
  // initial index to iterate `props`
  , n = 0;
  // if `d` set `prop` to `-180` , else set `prop` to `0`
  $(d ? {
    prop: -180
  } : {
    prop: 0
  }).animate(d ? {
    prop: 0
  } : {
    prop: -180
  }, {
    step: function(now) {
      // if `d` === `true` , set `css` utilizing `props` array
      if (d) {
        // reset `t` to rotation
        t.css("transform", p[++n]) 
      };
      // set `t` rotation
      t.css("transform", "rotate(" + now + "deg)");
      // push `css` `matrix` to `props`
      props.push(t.css("transform"));
    },
    duration: "slow",
    easing: "linear",
    complete: function() {
      // cache `r` current `.data("clicked")` value
      var r = t.data("clicked") === false ? true : false;
      // toggle effects with `r` as reference
      $(".engine").css("background-image", "url(/Incubator/wp-content/themes/incubator/images/" + (!r ? "basketball" : "engine") + ".jpg)");
      // adjusted `margin-left` properties to `0px`, `800px`
      t.add(".info-block").animate({
        "margin-left": !r ? "0px" : "800px"
      }, 1000);
      $(".alt")[!r ? "show" : "hide"]();
      $(".main")[!r ? "hide" : "show"]();
      $(".messy, .compete").fadeToggle("slow");
      // set `.data("clicked")` to `r`
      t.data("clicked", r);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-speed="5" class="engine parallax">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div data-pos="550" class="next fade-in triangle">next</div>
    <div data-pos="550" class="fade-in">
      <h3 class="messy">Get messy in the Incubator!</h3>
      <h3 class="compete">Compete in the Incubator!</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-pos="550" class="fade-in info-block">
      <p class="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p class="alt">Test text here sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
        esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <a href="">Get started today</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like it should work, but after the first click .next is gone but it acts like it is still there.  It won't call on .back click.  When you add a class can you not take an action on that added class?

Comment: Even if I remove the remove/add class from the .back it still doesn't work.  If I add both classes in the html then on click it runs through both animations.

Comment: If I run your code snippet if i click that next again it should just do the opposite and go back to the original data.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I had to do a little tweaking and I know it was a far stretch for what I asked but your answer helped me learn something in the process and I got it working as needed.